# OCSP Responder test error: bad hostname lookup

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, openssl, ocsp

When making a change to an nginx web server running on Ubuntu, I tested the nginx configuration and received the following warning:

> nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/"

I'd set up the web server a few months ago and had been updating the nginx configuration without seeing this warning until yesterday.

I started poking around and tested OCSP using openssl.

I ran the following command:

```
sudo openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pem -cert tm.pem -text -url http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/
```

with the following results

```
OCSP Request Data:
Version: 1 (0x0)
Requestor List:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha1
      Issuer Name Hash: 7EE66AE7729AB3FCF8A220646C16A12D6071085D
      Issuer Key Hash: A84A6A63047DDDBAE6D139B7A64565EFF3A8ECA1
      Serial Number: 03BD1754FBA80442EFE1CE2735DC96C598CF
Request Extensions:
    OCSP Nonce: 
        0410DC5C7354CF0C9838F66506F58A081AE3
Error connecting BIO
Error querying OCSP responder
140605810423448:error:2006A066:BIO routines:BIO_get_host_ip:bad hostname lookup:b_sock.c:146:host=ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
```

The website seems to work fine.

I can't find much info about the error. I don't know what changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: A) Thanks for reading the question B) I'll post the question in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, thanks for the suggestion. But... there seem to be plenty of nginx configuration questions on Stackoverflow and nginx is a part of me developing a website.

Comment: The issue seems to be a DNS issue. `dig ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org` fails.

Comment: After digging a bit (sorry, couldn't resist) I rebooted the server and all the DNS stuff seemed to fix itself. I'm writing a comment instead of an answer because I don't have an answer. I'd rebooted the server multiple times before over a period of time and that didn't fix the issue, so why the last reboot fixed the issue, I don't know.